# how to set picture on background of menu

Tags: android, xml, menu, background

Screen shot of activity here i want to add some icons on background same as on activity
[image: Screen shot of activity here i want to add some colors on background same as on activity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a style in res/values/styles.xml

`<style name="toolbarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#4286f4</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>`

Then apply that style in the xml of the toolbar

```
app:Theme="@style/toolbarStyle"
```

Comment: @Kyle can i set icons in menu...??